# Python Pandas: Sorting by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe (df)

```
A     object
B     object
C     int32
D     object
E     int32
F     float64
G     float64
H     float64
dtype: object
```

And I went to sort it using this code

```
df = df.sort_values(['C', 'E'], ascending=[0, 0])
```

and it sorted it by C correctly but not E at all. can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that your code should be fine as is. Perhaps you were not anticipating how sort_values works?

Suppose DataFrame df, the first two columns are object types and the next two are integers

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A object':['a',1,'b',2],
      'B object':['c',3,'d',4],
       'C int':[1,4,3,1],
       'E int':[0,4,2,1],
       'Strings', ['a','s','d','f']})
```

You want to sort by one column of integers and after that if there are identical values according to column 'C int' then sort those by column 'E int'

```
df.sort_values(by=['C int','E int'],ascending=[False,False])
```

You can not, however, simply sort by columns 'A object' or 'B object' as these contain both strings and integers. You can sort by 'Strings' but suppose you want to add this to the line ...

```
df.sort_values(by=['C int','E int','Strings'],ascending=[False,False,True])
```

The addition of the third criteria gives nothing new as their is no repetition in 'E int'

You can sort by 'Strings'

```
df.sort_values(by=['Strings'],ascending=[True])
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

This will sort the dataframe according to C first, then if column C matches, it will sort column E

```
df.sort(['C', 'E'])
```

Maybe you want to sort each column separately.  Something like...

```
new_c = df.sort('C')
df.drop("C", axis=1, inplace=True)
df["C"] = new_c
```